# MySQL Max Connections in Shared Hosting Environment

Tags: mysql, shared-hosting

I am having trouble with a website that I am responsible for, which is on a shared hosting plan. I'm unable to establish a database connection because there are too many in use. These lockouts (usually) line up with new events on the site, such as blog posts or tweets announcing blog posts.

When I connected to the database and asked for the value of the 'max_connections' variable, I found that it was set to 100.

```
SHOW variables LIKE 'max_connections';
```

I feel a bit silly asking this. Shared hosting means shared resources, it's right there in the name. But I'd like to confirm that this value that I'm getting is server-wide and not specific to my account.  Is my site reaching this number all on its own, or is it just one part of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maximum number of connections in MySQL can be limited globally, per user and per hour.

`max_connections` is global limit, `max_user_connections` for user.

Default max_connections is set to 100, if not changed from my.ini.

Comment: `max_user_connections` yielded 0, representing no limits in that regard. So I guess the `max_connections` speaks for the entire server. Unfortunately, the hosting company has stated that they do not want to increase this number. Thanks for the sanity check. :)

Comment: Yes, that's it :(